# Regex to match a specific pattern sequence

Tags: regex

I have a file including thousands of lines where the term `Found` is followed by a numerical value and another term `document(s)`. I would like to be able to match the pattern string+numerical+string and only extract the numerical value as I will need to find out what is the smallest and largest number.

Comment: Using what language/tool?

Comment: You can find a good tutorial here: http://www.regular-expressions.info/

Comment: @Casimir et Hippolyte thanks indeed, I have also made use of this: http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/grep-regular-expressions/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks for your replies. I must have specified that I am working in Linux with the bash shell Here the solution I came up with:

```
cat filename.txt | grep -w -o "string [0-9]\{1,\} string" > output.txt
```

This allowed me to match any number of digits greater than 1 and to output the list of string-number-string patterns to a text file.

Thanks,

I.

Answer (score 1):

Just a regex template

`string \s* (\d+) \s* string`

Where the digits are in capture buffer 1.

Comment: the spaces in your regex will literally match spaces, so you're saying there has to be a minimum of 2 consecutive spaces between each string and the number

Comment: @sln Thanks indeed for your help. Please see my working below. I have decided to use string [0-9]\{1,\} string